# Starting hiveserver2

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to run hiveserver2 on my hadoop cluster so that I can access hive using jdbc. I run the following command:
$HIVE_HOME/bin/hiveserver2. This doesn't log anything to STDOUTPUT but starts a process which is running, however I can't see any tcp sockets listening on the port 10000.

Turns out no socket is open for the process that hiveserver2 is running in.

How do I start hiveserver2?

Answer (score 31):

try running :
`hive --service hiveserver2 --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port=10000 --hiveconf hive.root.logger=INFO,console`
This will start hiveserver2, on port 10000 and output the logs to console.

Answer (score 6):

Use below command to run `hiveserver2` :

```
sudo su hduser

cd /usr/local/apache-hive-2.0.1-bin/bin

hive --service hiveserver2
```