# Hive Server 2 Hangs On Start / Won't Start

Tags: hive

I am trying to start hiveserver2, by going to the bin folder of my Hive install and typing hiveserver2. However, nothing happens - it just hangs there, and when I check if anything is running on Hive ports (the interface on 10002 for example) there is nothing, nor anything in netstat.

Initially I had errors about SLF4J:

```
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
```

But I solved that by moving the /usr/lib/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar in to the /tmp directory.

Now when I run bin/hiveserver2 it hangs for quite a while, with no output, and then just returns to the command line - and the Hive server isn't started. I'm struggling to find any logs either.

Comment: Okay, when I use:
hive --service hiveserver2 --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port=10000 --hiveconf hive.root.logger=INFO,console

It works and starts, but not when I just use hive --service hiveserver2... any ideas?

Comment: Probably the `hive` shell script does not build the CLASSPATH correctly -- both Hadoop and Log4J scan the CLASSPATH to find *directories*, then scan these directories to find config files with hard-coded names. I.e. `core-site.xml` etc. etc. `hive-site.xml` for Hive, and `log4j.properties` for you-guess-what. If no config file is found then the lib reverts (silently) to hard-coded default values, which may result in goofy error messages. Or weird behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that the hiveserver2 running without showing any information. Try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173113/starting-hiveserver2) with attached argument flag showing running log